# Xcode 6.0.1 iPhone only app behaves like a normal iPad app on iPad - iOS 8

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios8

I´ve just created a new iPhone only app with Xcode 6.0.1 -- when I run the app in the iPad simulator the app looks just like a normal iPad app (it´s an iPhone only app) --> I want that the app shows the upscaled iPhone version...

Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

BTW: I know that this issue only occurs when the LaunchScreen.xib is selected as Launch Screen File

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you configured an iPad launch screen? May be you can try by not configuring any.

Comment: Hmmm I haven´t found there is an option to select a LauchScreen.xib for iPhone only - generally I think the LaunchScreen.xib is used for both types iPhone & iPad

Comment: It's not a xib file. I'm talking about the image you use as launch screen. If you're using assets, look into your asset file and deselect iPad. Otherwise, check your target > General.

Comment: No I don´t use images at the launch screen just this new .xib file

Comment: I´ve just found a thread at the Apple Developer Forums - https://devforums.apple.com/message/1042051#1042051 - seems like a bug from Apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem.

I added following row to the info.plist file after reading this link http://openradar.io/18371031:

```
Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)    --> Main
```

It is now working iPhone only mode in my case.

Cheers,
Recai

Answer (score 0):

setting UILaunchStoryboardName~iphone instead of UILaunchStoryboardName in Info.plist helps me